# How to send rotated logs to rsyslog server?

Tags: linux, redhat, rsyslog

I want to send all the rotated logs from client to my rsyslog server.

I already tried using the modfile, but it sends the running logs not the rotated logs (gunzip).

Answer (score 0):

Use rsync to transfer the rotated logs to your rsyslog server. This command can be scheduled via cron or another scheduler.

```
rsync -avz --remove-source-files /path/to/your/logs/*.gz user@rsyslog_server:/path/to/destination/
```

Ensure that your rsyslog server is configured to receive logs. Modify your rsyslog configuration file (commonly found in /etc/rsyslog.conf or /etc/rsyslog.d/) to include a rule for the incoming logs.

```
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFileName /path/to/destination/*.gz
$InputFileTag rotated_logs:
$InputFileStateFile stat-rotated_logs
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local7
$InputRunFileMonitor
```

Restart rsyslog

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```